# MySqlConnection is not closing inside `using` statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing MVC application which is using MySql and problem is i get error `too many connections`. This is confusing to me because i am wrapping connection initializer inside `using` and it should dispose of it automatically.

Example of code:

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    con.Open();
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(...))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the reason it does drop me this error and what to do?

Comment: Is there any other place in your code in which you might not use the `using` statement ?

Comment: You could decrease the wait_timeout: `wait_timeout=500`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout. `using` only helps when an exception happens, you are already closing the connection, which is the same as disposing it. The problem is that MySQL keeps the connections alive for too long, new connections are created faster than old ones are destroyed. Hence you can try this method.

Comment: It sounds like ADO.NET has a connection pool size that is bigger than the maximum number of connections allowed by the server. Specify "max pool size" in your connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The using statement calls Dispose explictly. So it's not because it leaves connections open. They are disposed correctly by default and by design.

Try adding "Pooling=false" to your connection string. Or perhaps call ClearPool().

Comment: I have done it and i will update question and accept answer when few days passes to be sure it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you ignoring `using` statement with using `con.Open()`. It will be open connection several times.

Can you try this ,

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
  using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(...))
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

or ,

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString)) // --> First connection opening here
{
con.Open(); // --> And second connection opening here.
  using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(...))
  {
     ...
  }
con.Close(); // --> Second is closing here
} // --> First one is closing here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check connection state and close it if it's open, then open it. You trying to create new connection when you have a connection already. So, you getting runtime connection error.

```
  if (con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
  {
      con.Close();
  }
      con.Open();
```